# Claiming costs if a faulty product causes property damage

Tags: england-and-wales, warranties

I received a faulty sports product which broke during first use. The breakage was caused by [incorrect fasteners being supplied with the product](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/43097/claiming-statutory-warranty-for-a-fault-that-resulted-in-the-loss-of-the-product). The incident in question caused significant damage to another piece of equipment, in addition to a small injury (broken toe).

Is it reasonable for me to claim repair costs from the retailer/manufacturer of product that caused the issue?

Comment: You really got some bad luck. That's your second problem with incorrect fasteners being supplied with a product.

Comment: @gnasher729 as luck would have it, this morning I found the very expensive bit that missing. It did involve splashing around in the ocean at 5am this morning :D